# Http-Header in Apache

Tags: apache, http-headers

The HTTP request header "User-Agent" can be fetched from an Apache cgi program with "HTTP_USER_AGENT", the header "Content-Length" with "CONTENT_LENGTH".
How can you get the request header "SOAPAction"?

Do you have to write "HTTP_SOAPACTION", "HTTP_SOAP_ACTION", "SOAPACTION" or "SOAP_ACTION"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "HTTP_SOAPACTION".

According to [RFC 3875](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875#section-4.1.18):

> Meta-variables with names beginning with "HTTP_" contain values
> read    from the client request header fields, if the protocol used is
> HTTP.    The HTTP header field name is converted to upper case, has
> all    occurrences of "-" replaced with "`_`" and has "HTTP_" prepended
> to    give the meta-variable name.